# titlesec \clearpage before a part

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, titlesec, parts

I'm using the `titlesec` package for my sectioning. I want to have a `\clearpage` before every `\part` however when I put it into the `format` field of

```
\titleformat{command}[shape]{format}{label}{sep}{before-code}{after-code}
```

Then it does what I want, but if the very first part of the document (which is incidentally the first content after the `\maketitle` command, it will insert a blank page. This is because, to quote the [titlesec documentation](http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf),

> `{format}` is the format to be applied to the whole title—label and text. This part can contain vertical material (and horizontal with some shapes) which is typeset just after the space above the title

Note the ''just after the space above the title'. So `\clearpage` should not be put into the `format` field.

I can do the same thing that I want to do, but with sections, not parts, using

```
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
```

I know there are other commands just like that for things such as `subsubsection` or `subsection`, but I couldn't find one for `part` that worked. How would I do it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\part}[display]{\clearpage\itshape\rmfamily\raggedright}{\LARGE Part     \thepart}{0mm}{\Huge}{}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0mm}{30mm}{30mm}

\begin{document}
\part{Part test}
test text
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that the community can play with. It really helps...

Comment: One suggestion could be to add `\partbreak` as part of the `<format>` for your `\part`, where `\newcommand{\partbreak}{}`. Then, exactly from where you need to insert the `\clearpage`, add `\renewcommand{\partbreak}{\clearpage}`.

Comment: @Werner Yeap, sorry, I was pressed for time. Updated the question with MWE. Regarding your second comment, I was looking more for some sure way to always have it on a new page, a bit like the effect of `\sectionbreak`above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more appropriate way of inserting a `\clearpage` before *every* `\part` is to redefine `\part` in the following way:

```
\let\oldpart\part% Store \part in \oldpart
\renewcommand{\part}{\clearpage\oldpart}% Insert \clearpage before every \part
```

Use this *after* specifying `\titleformat` for `\part`.

Answer (score 5):

Simplest solution seems to be to declare `\part` to be of `top` class; then you can use `\partbreak` and define it to be `\clearpage` as desired:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\itshape\rmfamily\raggedright}{\LARGE Part \thepart}{0mm}{\Huge}{}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0mm}{30mm}{30mm}
\titleclass{\part}{top}
\newcommand\partbreak{\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\part{Part test}
test text
\part{Part test}
test text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you actually need the `\newcommand\partbreak{\clearpage}` here?  `\titleclass{\part}{top}` seems to do this (although in the wrong order compared with updating the counter, see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162431))