# Parts with titlesec parts: \thepart wrong on last page of part

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, numbering, titlesec

When using the `titlesec` package to customize part headers, the counter `\thepart` is somehow incremented before its value is used in, for example, running headers:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% If you do not issue the \titleformat command, everything is fine
\titleformat{\part}[display]
            {\bfseries\huge\filcenter}
            {\partname\ \thepart%
             % A working hack: set the mark here instead, expanding \thepart
             % (note the lack of \protect)
             %\markright{Part \thepart, page \protect\thepage} 
            }
            {20pt}
            {\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{*36}{*1}

\begin{document}
\part{Intro}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

% Remove this to see the hack work.
\markright{Part \protect\thepart, page \protect\thepage}

This page should have ``\textsl{Part \thepart, page \thepage}'' at the top.
\newpage
This page should have ``\textsl{Part \thepart, page \thepage}'' at the top.
\part{A Problem}                % This command does the incrementing
\end{document}
```

Page 3 – the last page in Part I – is the problem:

[image: Demonstration of \thepart counter error on page 3]

Somehow the second `\part{A Problem}` is advancing the counter before the counter is used in the header.

What exactly is the problem, and what is the suggested fix?  One can hack a solution as shown, saving the value of the `\thepart` counter when the part is typeset, but this is not a satisfactory solution as I would like a user to be able to use the counter in custom headers etc.

The `titlesec` manual notes that parts are somewhat unique and non-starndard, but this seems like a bug to me.

**Update**

In response to the answer by @hugovdberg, I can trace the problem to the following definition in `titlesec.sty`:

```
\makeatletter\def\ttl@page@i#1[#2]#3{%
  \gdef\ttl@savemark{\csname#1mark\endcsname{#3}}%
  \def\ttl@savewrite{\ttl@write{#1}{#3}}%  A default value. Not #2!
  \def\ttl@savetitle{#3}%
  \ttl@labelling{#1}{#2}%
  \ttl@startargs\ttl@page@ii{#1}{#3}}
```

The `\clearpage` commands that will cause the headers to be processed is inside the 
 `\ttl@startargs\ttl@page@ii{#1}{#3}` call while the part counter is increased in the previous `\ttl@labelling{#1}{#2}` call.  Switching the order of these fixes the problem, but I do not know if there are other consequences.  Seems like a bug to me.

**Second Update**

There are some questions about why I need to `\protect\thepage`: it is because `\markright` expands its arguments, but because of the way the standard classes reset the headers each time, this forces me to call `\markright` after each part, so using an expanded (unprotected) `\thepart` will appear to solve the problem.  Here is a second, not quit MWE that uses `fancyhdr` to demonstrate that there really is a problem, and it has nothing to do with protection:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Now I can do this once and for all: no protection needed.
\chead{Part \thepart, page \thepage}

% If you do not issue the \titleformat command, everything is fine
\titleformat{\part}[display]
            {\bfseries\huge\filcenter}
            {\partname\ \thepart%
             % A working hack: set the mark here instead, expanding \thepart
             % (note the lack of \protect)
             %\markright{Part \thepart, page \protect\thepage} 
            }
            {20pt}
            {\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{*36}{*1}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\part{Intro}

This page should have ``\textsl{Part \thepart, page \thepage}'' at the top.
\newpage
This page should have ``\textsl{Part \thepart, page \thepage}'' at the top.
\part{A Problem}                % This command does the incrementing

A new page
\end{document}
```

[image: Demonstration of problem with fancyhdr and no protection]

### Related

- [Problems with part-labels using titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6609): Addresses related issues with the part label, noting that `titlesec` does some strange things with parts. The answer there does not solve this problem.
- [titlesec: \assignpagestyle problem with part](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117354): Also mentions some issues with parts, but not obviously related to this question.

Comment: I tried sending a bug report on the page http://www.tex-tipografia.com/contact.html but the form failed.

Comment: I'm seeing this and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Why are you protecting `\thepart` in `\markright` (you shouldn't). If I remove `\protect` it works.

Comment: Because `\markright` expands its arguments.  This is a little hard to demonstrate with the standard classes since I need to reset the header each time, but is easy to show with the KOMA classes.  (I thought at first it might be a KOMA/titlesec issue, but it is not.)  I will update the MWE shortly with will use `fancyhdr`: there expansion is not done, and using an unprotected `\thepart` fails exactly as here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `\part{A Problem}` is executed on the last page of your first part, and the value of `\thepart` is the part number at the **end** of the current page. Since you start a new part on that page, even though the part title is printed on the next, your part counter is increased. The solution is to manually enter a `\newpage` before `\part`. This will not create superfluous empty pages since `\part` will only insert blank pages to get to a recto page.

**Edit** To automatically insert this for every part the accepted answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126138/titlesec-clearpage-before-a-part) could be used.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% If you do not issue the \titleformat command, everything is fine
\titleformat{\part}[display]
            {\bfseries\huge\filcenter}
            {\partname\ \thepart%
             % A working hack: set the mark here instead, expanding \thepart
             % (note the lack of \protect)
             %\markright{Part \thepart, page \protect\thepage} 
            }
            {20pt}
            {\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{*36}{*1}

\let\oldpart\part
\renewcommand{\part}{\clearpage\oldpart}

\begin{document}
\part{Intro}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

% Remove this to see the hack work.
\markright{Part \protect\thepart, page \protect\thepage}

This page should have ``\textsl{Part \thepart, page \thepage}'' at the top.
\newpage
This page should have ``\textsl{Part \thepart, page \thepage}'' at the top.
\part{A Problem}                % This command does the incrementing
\end{document}
```

Comment: That makes sense, but one should be able to get away without having to do this.  Does the standard `\part` command do this in a way that `titlesec` fails to redefine properly?

Comment: Apparently this is a known problem with the `titlesec` package, updated my answer to include the a `\clearpage` automatically.

Comment: Can you point me to a discussion about the "known problem"?  It seems to me that the correct answer to the [question you mention](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126138) should actually be `\titleclass{\part}{top}` (the highest voted answer), but that does not fix my issue either.  The solution of adding `\clearpage` to every part does work, but still seems like a hack: I think it should be possible to emulate the standard `book` behaviour without resorting to hacks like this.

Comment: What I meant to say is that this problem occurs to other people as well. As I said, the hack of adding a `\clearpage` comes without a penalty. Besides, it really wouldn't surprise me if the standard `book` behaviour is to do a `\clear(double)page` first and then increment the counter, whereas this is somehow swapped in the `titlesec` package. By the way, at least this hack works whereas the highest voted answer apparently doesn't ;-)

Comment: Yes - the standard classes do exactly that.  I think I am convinced now that there is a bug in `titlesec`, and that the correct way to deal with it until it gets fixed is the `\clearpage` hack, so I will accept your answer until `titlesec` is fixed.

Comment: Not a bug. Just use marks as described in LaTeX manuals and no hack is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `\protect` before `\thepart`. The mark mechanism relies on its expansion when the mark is *emitted* and not when it's typeset. You are protecting `\thepart` and therefore it gets expanded in the headline, but at that point the value can be the wrong one. On the other hand, `\thepage` must be protected, because it's supposed to print the value when the headline is typeset, not when the mark is emitted.

**EDIT** For the same reason, `\thepart` mustn't be used directly in heads/foots (well, you can if you are using `titleps`, which `hides' the mark mechanism). Just use marks, which are the correct mechanism to pass info to headlines. See my comment below.

Comment: I understand the idea here – it was the basis for what I called my "hack" – but my second example using `fancyhdr` should clarify that the standard mechanism does not rely on expansion of the mark at definition time.  Instead, the standard mechanism ensures that the page is cleared before `\thepart` is incremented, which I think is the bug in `titlesec`.

Comment: It seems it should be easy to fix `titlesec` so that the `\clearpage` occurs before the counter is updated, but I am afraid to suggest a full bugfix as I am most-likely unaware of additional unintended side-effects of rearranging things at a high level.  Do you have some regression tests for `titlesec` behaviour?  If so, I would feel more confident taking a stab at fixing this.  I *really* appreciate `titlesec` and would love for it to work flawlessly.  Fixing KOMA compatibility would also be fantastic... (P.S. I still can't send you a note with your web form.)

Comment: Nope. Where the counter is increased is irrelevant - what's relevant is where the mark is emitted. The example with `fancyhdr` is wrong, too, because you are using `\thepart` in the the headline, and its value must be passed in a mark. This is the whole point of the mark mechanism! No bug here - just pass the info to headlines as explained in LaTeX manuals.